# Represent the following curves in the z-plane in the form z(t)

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Represent the following curve in the z-plane in the form z=z(t).

$$y = {x^2}\quad 1 \le x \le 3
$$

I know the answer is $$z(t) = t + i{t^2}\quad 1 \le t \le 3
$$ however I don't have any idea how to arrive at that answer.

Comment: For a cheap answer: Start with $z=x+iy,$ and consider what difference it makes to relabel $x$ to $t$.

Comment: @Semiclassical that helps me with this problem only, there is no connection i can relate to similar problems

Answer (score 1):

z=z(t)= x(t) + i y(t)
Now if you set x = t then as y=x² , we get y=t² .
So we write z=t+it²